# prove or give a counterexample: for every vector space V over ℝ and every v∈ V, there exists w∈ V such that w≠ cv for any c∈ℝ.

Tags: linear-algebra

prove or give a counterexample: for every vector space V over ℝ and every v$\in$V, there exists w$\in$V such that w$\neq$cv for any c$\in$ℝ.

I am not sure where to begin, any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are not sure where to begin, think of trivial examples. Take for example $V=\Bbb R$ or $V=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: any one-dimensional vector space.

Comment: how about 2-dimensional vector space? Does it work then?

Comment: Yes. In dimension >1 it always works. Take your vector v. And take an element w that is linearly independent from v.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: any zero-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Even more trivial than my answer! +1

Comment: @EpsilonDelta You've answered the question (hope the OP accepts your answer soon), I was just tempted to copy it :)

Comment: Haha I had a laugh when I read it. Your anwer is as correct as mine so let the OP  choose which answer he accepts!